# Matlab - 2D concentration/contour plot

Tags: matlab, plot, 2d, gradient, contour

2D matlab Contour plot - concentration map

I have two sets of data

x = (x1, x2, x3....)
y = (y1, y2, y3....)

which describe the cartesian co-ordinates of a set of points in the plane. So x1y1 is the coordinate of object 1 and so on.

The coordinates are restricted to certain values: a minimum (0) and maximum value which describe the dimensions of the plane (which is a rectangle).

For example, the coordinates might describe the position of objects in a room, or trees in a field or so on.

How can I represent these co-ordinates (the two sets of data) as a 2D contour/concentration plot using matlab? i.e rather than just dots on the plane (a scatter graph) a smooth continuous colour map/

kind regards
W

Comment: Do you have a value for each `x` and `y` location?

Comment: Hu Suever, yes I have two vectors/arrays: x = (x1, x2, x3....) y = (y1, y2, y3....). Each value is unique and is a number. So it might be like: x = (1,5,7,8,3....); y = (5,6,3,2,5,8...) etc. So this means there is an object at (1,5) another at (5,6), another at (7,3) and so on. I have (potentially) thousands of objects. Thanks, W

Comment: That's not what I asked. You have `x` and `y` but do you have a value for each combination of `x` and `y`? `f(x,y)`

Answer (score 0):

It is not really obvious what you are asking. Remember for making a contour you need another set of data besides x and y.

I think what you are trying to achieve can be done using `meshgrid` which gives you a proper mesh on your data:

```
x = rand(1,20);
y = rand(1,20);
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
Z = zeros(size(X));
mesh(X,Y,Z);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Generate a matrix where every value is a coordinate region and add 1 for every point in that region.

So for example you have points (0.5,0.7) (0.9,0.8) (1.5,0.6) (1.8,1.2)

And you map this to a matrix where every value corresponds to a "square" of a value region 1x1.

```
a(1,1) = everything in the region 0 <= x < 1, 0 <= y < 1
a(1,2) = everything in the region 0 <= x < 1, 1 <= y < 2
a(2,1) = everything in the region 1 <= x < 2, 0 <= y < 1
a(2,2) = everything in the region 1 <= x < 2, 1 <= y < 2
```

So you would get `[2 1;0 1]` and then you can contour it.

If you need a finer resolution just decrease the mapping size.

I can't give you a code solution on the fly because my Matlab is a bit rusty, but the principle should work fine.